# Google Maps API to get directions using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to make Google Maps automatically set driving routes for destinations that are stored in my database. Basically, I have a few addresses in my databases(i.e: manufacturers) and I want to be able to enter a zip code(or an address) to receive the directions from that zipcode/address to all the manufacturers available(and maybe for a fancy extra, fetch the closest manufacturer). I've never used Google Maps API before so I'm fairly confused by it. So far, I've only been able to set markers to the available manufacturers. As for the driving routes, I've looked for hours and it's a bit complex to digest. What way would you suggest me to take(no pun intended) with this piece of code that I have so far?

```
echo "<script>
        var locations = 
        [
        ";
            for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($locations); $i++)
            {
                echo "['".$locations[$i][0]."', '".$locations[$i][1]."', ".$locations[$i][2].", ".$locations[$i][3].", ". ($i+1) ." ]";
                if (! ($i == (sizeof($locations)-1)) )
                    echo ",";
            }
        echo "];

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), 
        {
            zoom: 15,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.892235, -72.5371626),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        var marker, i;

        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) 
        {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker(
            {
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][2], locations[i][3]),
                map: map
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) 
            {
                return function() {
                infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
          })(marker, i));
        }
</script>";
```

Comment: use json_encode php function to encode location array http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php

Comment: @RolandoCorratgeNieves Why would I do that exactly?

Comment: try `echo "location=".json_encode($x).";";`   and see what you get maybe you can replace the whole for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have a first answer to your problem, hope this can help.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  var locations = [
    ["a","Title A",46.3,-72.5],
    ["b","Title B",45.9,-72.4],
    ["c","Title C",45.6,-72.1]
  ] ;

  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById('map'), 
    {
      zoom: 7,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.892235, -72.5371626),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
  );

  jQuery(locations).each(function(k,v) {
    
    locations[k].push('what s in index 4 ?') ; // Push in index 4
    
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(v[2],v[3]),
      map: map,
      title: v[1]
    })
    locations[k].push(marker) ;

  }) ;

  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
  var directionDisplays = [] ; // We need to store displays to be abled to remove them on each "getRoute" click.

  document.getElementById('getRoutes').addEventListener('click', getRoutes);

  function getRoutes() {

   // Removing existing routes if any
    for ( i = 0 ; i < directionDisplays.length ; i++ )
      directionDisplays[i].setMap(null) ;

    directionDisplays = [] ;

    // Now the important part : for each location we look for the route
    jQuery(locations).each(function(k,v) {
     
     directionsService.route({
         origin: document.getElementById('whereami').value,
           destination: new google.maps.LatLng(v[2],v[3]) ,
           travelMode: 'DRIVING'
        }, function (response, status) {
          if (status === 'OK') {
           // This callback is call asynchronous, this is probably why it's complicated to access locations[k]
            var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer ;
            directionsDisplay.setMap(map) ;
            // We remove the marker "B" added by directionsDisplay.
            directionsDisplay.setOptions( { suppressMarkers: true } );
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            directionDisplays.push(directionsDisplay) ;
            var point = response.routes[ 0 ].legs[ 0 ];

            // We affect the direction to the marker to make it accessible later
            locations[k][5].duration = point.distance.text ;

            // And know we just have to add a listener.
      locations[k][5].addListener('click',function(){
         console.log(this.title,this.duration) ;
      }) ;

          } else {
            window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
          }
       }
      );
    }) ;
  }

}) ;
```

```css
div#map {
width:50% ;
height:250px ;
float:left ;
}

div#boutons {
float:right;
width:200px ;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="boutons">
  <input type="text" id="whereami" value="Ottawa" />
  <button id="getRoutes">get routes</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, it works like a charm. However, I thought the API let you automatically click on a route to select it(like on Google Maps). Is there a way to do so or do I have to draw the routes myself using polylines?

Comment: I don't think you can add a click listener on the directionsDisplay, maybe you should take a look at the response object, it could contain the complete path so you can draw it yourself instead of using `directionsDisplay.setMap(map) ; directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);`.

Comment: Excellent, instead of clicking on routes, I've added an event listener to each marker so it would display the travel distance and travel time. However, it's only working on the last location within the loop. It's as if the response from the API is slow that it only fetches the last result(and for some reason outputs the results the same amount of time as the loop value)

Comment: You should consider to add your actual code so we can see where you are

Comment: https://pastebin.com/4QQhuXFT
see "alert(name);" that's where it outputs the last location name 4 times(I have 4 locations in the database) whereas it should output every location name.

Comment: First of all you have a problem with the marker positionned by directionDisplay : it can be removed with directionsDisplay.setOptions( { suppressMarkers: true } );. Then you should create markers before and store them so you can access them after the async callback : you can see in my answer i've edited so the distance is shown in console on marker click.